# Strategy for making a mobile version of a EPiServer site

Tags: asp.net, mobile-website, jquery-mobile, episerver

I am about to help a client develop a mobile version of their EPiServer site. The mobile version should have different functionality than the regular but some content might be shared so that it won't have be maintained twice.

I'm thinking about using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) as the user interface system to reach as many users as possible with the same solution and possibly [51degrees.mobi](http://51degrees.mobi/) for best detection of mobile devices.

Does anyone have any experience in how to do this with EPiServer? How to structure? I'm thinking of using a sub-node (/mobile) that gets hidden on the regular site but I'm not sure it's the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want content in one place without having your editors work with "Fetch data from" a sub-node won't work.

The best option is probably to have "one content serve all" and have a cookie that says "mobile" OR "full site". The default mode can be determined by detection. If mobile is selected then you serve different CSS/JS or even other page properties or functionality.

Another option is to make use of the globalization mechanism and add "Mobile" as a language. This could be an easy way for editors to create separate mobile content if needed and keep the original content for other pages. I recall you can add different top domains for different languages without violating the license agreement so you could have a .mobi-name for the mobile "language".

Comment: Does the main language and the mobile "language" have to be in sync or is it possible to have a totally different structure?

Comment: You can leave pages out in one language. There's different configurations if you want fall back support or not. It's also easy to write code around which language is selected and if pages exist for it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following blog post:
[IPhone Optimalization Made Easy](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Mari-Jorgensen/Dates/2010/4/IPhone-Optimization-Made-Easy/)

It demonstrates how to build mobile-friendly websites using HTML, conditional CSS and jquery - all in EPiServer

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://www.epinova.no/blog/Anders-Murel/dates/2012/5/flexible-episerver-mobile-content-strategy-with-epinovamobiletemplateprovider/

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies. Also, please review our [FAQ#promotion] on linking to your own blog.